How to apply the '~' prefix to a hotkey but still block its default shortcut function?
Lets say I have x key, and I want use it as a "modifier" so that I can combine it with other hotkeys, like so:

x & and y
x & and w
x & and z

In order to do this, I need to use ~:
#singleinstance, force
~x::
;~$x::                   ;I tried this, thinking '$' to mean to disables the keys default function. Didnt work
tooltip, X pressed
return
x & y::
tooltip, X and Y pressed
return

But now, the active windows shortcut for x will also fire, in some windows this could be simply typing x, in others firing a command. In effect AutoHotkey fails in blocking x.
This has been a issue that has been plaguing me for a long time, ~ will allow you to combine its hotkey with other keys but then also disables AHKs ability to block the hotkeys default shortcut.
This int really a AhkV1/V2 issue. I am sure the same issues is present in V2 as well

You can't. The tilde prefix (~)  prevents AHK from blocking the  key-down/up events. It allows the key event to pass through. See also Custom Combinations.

hmm, I see. Thank you for the expalanation.

I ran a brief test, and it seems it's possible. I have used my appskey to more easily use arrow keys for navigation, but have also put in a definition for just pressing the key. Defining the default action is important, otherwise only the combinations will work.
;Use appskey as modifier to get home/end/pgup/pgdn at a useful place
AppsKey::Send, {AppsKey}
AppsKey & Up::PgUp
AppsKey & Down::PgDn
AppsKey & Left::Home
AppsKey & Right::End

In your case, the code could look like this (in one-liner, as there's only one thing to do)
x::tooltip, X pressed
x & y::tooltip, X and Y pressed

